# Spherical functions - symbol in solution

Tags: notation, spherical-harmonics

What does the symbol on the right-hand side of eq. (4.9) mean, please?
[image: equations]

Comment: Which one?  (1) $\Phi$, (2) $\varphi$, (3) $\Xi$, (4) $\vartheta$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\Xi$ is Greek letter Xi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Phi$ and $\Xi$ are functions of only $\varphi$ and $\vartheta$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @ElenaGreg. They make an *Ansatz* that $Y_n(\vartheta, \varphi)$ can be written as such a product. This is a common method of solving partial differential equations.

Comment: Many thank for you answers